# Enable Reply on Facebook posts

Tags: facebook

I see posts by some FB friends where the Reply link is enabled on comments made on the post to facilitate conversation threads. They haven't done anything special to enable this feature. This is a personal FB profile, not a commercial FB page. I'm in the US.

Why does one account have the feature enabled and not others? I see that FB added this feature for commercial pages/groups back in [2013](https://www.facebook.com/notes/journalists-on-facebook/improving-conversations-on-facebook-with-replies/578890718789613) but I don't see anything about how to enable this for personal accounts. There are some [hacks](http://www.safetricks.com/2015/02/add-reply-button-facebook-comments.html) out there but I am pretty sure none of my friends have done that yet they still have the feature.

How can I get the feature?

Comment: I think its an automatic process. This feature enabled on my FB automatically someday back.